# Python try and catch is not working in jupyter note book

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

HI I am new to jupyter notebook.
I am not sure why this block of code executes both try and except in my code

```
print('time :' , datetime.now())
try:  
    print("Command executed")
    pd.read_sql('''select * from table  ''')
    print("Command executed")
except:
    print("Command skipped")
```

Here is the output I am getting

```
time : 2022-12-07 06:40:37.294965
Command executed
Command skipped
```

Comment: bcuz you have `Command executed` before and after pd.read_sql?

Comment: You check points should be different..You alredy used `Command executed` ...user different check point after query to see diffrence

Comment: Even after removing print("Command executed") after pd.read_sql the same output is coming

Comment: You need to remove the one _before_ reading the db

Comment: @gimix even after that i dont see output of jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

You check points should be different..You alredy used Command executed ...user different check point after query to see diffrence.

```
print('time :' , datetime.now())
try:  
    print("Execution started")
    pd.read_sql('''select * from table  ''')
    print("Command executed")
except:
    print("Command skipped")
```